# RewriteRule in directory in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect same file.php to html in a directory, but not work.

```
RewriteRule ^directory\file.html?$  directory/file.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Redirect or rewrite? `file.php` to `file.html` _or_ `file.html` to `file.php`. You need to describe in natural language what it is you are trying to do. Your description and code sample contradict each other. How exactly does it "not work"?

Comment: sorry, i need file.php to file.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to redirect same file.php to html in a directory

To "redirect" `/dir/file.php` to `/dir/file.html` then you would do something like the following at the top of your root `.htaccess` file (assuming you already have a `RewriteEngine On` directive):

```
RewriteRule ^dir/file\.php$ /dir/file.html [R,L]
```

On the other hand...

> ```
> RewriteRule ^directory\file.html?$  directory/file.php [L,NC]
> ```

This is an *internal rewrite* (not a "redirect") in the opposite direction (from `file.html` to `file.php`), although your syntax is also incorrect (backslash instead of *forward* slash, failure to escape literal dot, optional `l`?).